# Has anyone managed to get the iPad iOS 10 simulator to trigger a shake event?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios10, motion

Broken suddenly in iOS 10 simulators.

Prepare with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit:YES];
```

Implement:

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

And the -motionBegan is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that they have changed how this works, and my "Prepare" above is now insufficient in iOS 10. You don't need to set that.

Now you must implement the motionBegan in the first responder that will receive the event, if it is your VC you need to implement:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```